# Secondary Alphabetical Order

Tags: word, letters, letter-sequence

Here are the **final 16 Official Letters** of the **Secondary Alphabetical Order**:

> **..
>
>   ..
>
>   K, L, A, I, U,
>
>   G, R, H, N, F,
>
>   B, X, O, Q, J,
>
>   Z**

If you can figure out the rest of the order, the **first five Official Letters** will tell you how official letters should be written.

Comment: i wonder what the _first five Official Letters_ will tell us if we can't figure out the rest of the order?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Official letters should be ...

> ... **typed**.

The Secondary Alphabetical Order is ...

> ... determined by the keys of the NATO Phonetic Alphabet, but without their first letters:
>
> ```
>       T·ango      Y·ankee     P·apa       E·cho       D·elta
>       C·harlie    W·hiskey    V·ictor     S·ierra     M·ike
>       K·ilo       L·ima       A·lpha      I·ndia      U·niform
>       G·olf       R·omeo      H·otel      N·ovember   F·oxtrot
>       B·ravo      X·ray       O·scar      Q·uebec     J·ulett
>       Z·ulu
> ```