# Another Secondary Alphabetical Order

Tags: letters, letter-sequence

Here is another [Secondary Alphabetical Order](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92524/28719):

> [image]

If you can figure out the rest of the order, the arrows will hint you how the letters should be written.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key of the order is:

> Morse code representation of each alphabet (`-` is smaller than `.` in ASCII)
>
> ```
>  T -     ←
>  M --
>  O ---   ←
>  G --.
>  Q --.-
>  Z --..
>  N -.
>  K -.-
>  Y -.--
>  C -.-.
>  D -..   ↔︎
>  X -..-
>  B -...
>  E .
>  A .-    →
>  W .--
>  J .---
>  P .--.
>  R .-.
>  L .-..
>  I ..
>  U ..-
>  F ..-.
>  S ...   →
>  V ...-
>  H ....  →
> ```

The arrows mean:

> If we read letters with leftward arrows(←) from right to left, it says **DOT**.
>
>  If we read letters with rightward arrows(→) from left to right, it says **DASH**.
>
>  **Morse code** uses **dot**s and **dash**es, obviously!

Comment: Great job! Absolutely correct :D